# Database design decision for storing files

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Hi I am working on a personal application and am facing a database design decision that I do not know which course of action to take.Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

In my application I will store a lot of images , videos and some html files build with a WYSIWYG editor .I have already decided that I will not be storing in my database the file but instead I will only store the original file name and the storage file name(unique identifier).

To that end I decided that it would be a good idea to have 3 separate tables for each type of file.

This is where I started to hit some problems.

At the moment , after I analyzed what I was trying to build , I realized that so far I have 4 types of images : avatars , thumbnails , description , headers.And this list may grow until I am finished with the application.The same could be said for the videos and html files , I am not sure yet.

As of now I see 2 courses of action in designing my database.

The first one is that I have one Images table in which I will have ths properties:

OriginalFileName ,StorageFileName , IsAvatar , IsThumbnail , IsDescription , IsHeader

In this case every time I identify a new type of image in my app I will have to modify the database table , witch does not sound right to me.

The second one is that I create tables for each type of Image.

In this case I would have 4 tables that would have a Primary column , a OriginalFileName column and a StorageFileName column.

Again every type I identify a new type of Image a new table will have to be created.

This solution kind of sounds right but I could be entering the overengineering teritory by doing things like this.

So what would be the best solution for my current problem?

I am opened to hear alternative options if anyone has any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're suggesting (both suggestions) is called denormalisation; in a relational database this can be a bad thing. If avatars, thumbnails, descriptions and headers have the same attributes, i.e. only a original file name and a storage filename they should all go in one table, certainly, but you only need a single column to identify which is which. You then have a second table to decode this.

For instance:

You have a table, with columns

```
Files
    OriginalFileName, StorageFileName, FileTypeID
```

The FileTypeID would then be a foreign key into a second table:

```
FileTypes
    ID, Description
    1   Avatar
    2   Thumbnail
    3   Description
    4   Header
```

If you then want to add another type of file you add another row to FileTypes and start populating the table Files.

If your files have different attributes then you might want to consider 4 separate tables but not until that point.

Answer (score 3):

You could sub-type your tables.  Have one which stores the images themselves:

```
Images
----------------
ID
OriginalFileName
StorageFileName
```

Then for the subtypes their primary keys would be foreign keys back to the supertype table:

```
Avatars
---------------
ID (FK to Images.ID)

Thumbnails
---------------
ID (FK to Images.ID)

etc.
```

This would allow you to easily add/remove types as well as add/remove data associated with specific types without having to modify structures unrelated to those particular changes.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in different ways depending upon my application requirements. For example, I have split the files based on long-term storage vs. short term storage since that was an important distinction in the files. But unless I have a very specific reason for splitting the files into subtypes, I just treat the files as typeless data (as far as the database is concerned) in that the file reference table has all the the metadata that I want to capture, with lookup tables to interpret the metadata. Ignoring indices, etc.

```
create table FileRef
(
  FileName varhchar(80) not null
, FileExt varchar(30) null
, FileClass smallint not null
, CreateUTC datatime not null
, Modified datetime not null
, Description varchar(250) null
)
GO

/*
You might want a computed column for the filename+Extentsion. I have have that splitting out the extension is often useful in the database so I don't have to parse it out whenever I want it.
*/

create table FileClass
(
  smallint id not null
, Description varchar(80) not null
, Location varchar(80) not null
)
GO
```

Of course, alter the previous tables to suit your needs.

I also recommend not storing the path to the disk files in the FileRef (as shown above, I store this in FileClass) as this makes is easier to move the files around when you have to move the files due to server changes, etc.

If the volume of files will be large, you will not want to put all of the files in a single folder. Although modern versions of windows maintain disk directories in a btree, you will encounter issues like accidentally opening explorer in a large directory that make it very unpleasant with a million files. A simple split of files of perhaps 4K files per directory -- perhaps based on the TSQL CHECKSUM() will prevent this from being a problem.

OOPS, forgot important field, you also want a FileID of some form in FileRef.